# Java MongoDB Rest Client

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

Are there any java-based MongoDB rest client?

- That can be included in a Java app
- And provides access Restful access to most MongoDB functions
- And perhaps use `HttpClient` as the base client to do HTTP methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MongoDB docs they have a section on [HTTP interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/):

One of them is a Java Server.

[Mongodb Java REST server](https://sites.google.com/site/mongodbjavarestserver/home)

You did ask for a Java Client and not a server, but I thought it might be a step in the right direction, and will open up Restful access to MongoDB functions, which was one of your criteria.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: I mean, I really can't find any Java Rest client for MongoDB

Comment: I am not sure I understand? You want a rest client? Something that sits on your server and sends HTTP Requests to another server with MongoDB on it to query it? So do you already have a MongoDB Server? If you already have a MongoDB REST server, can you not use any Java CURL library to make the interactions? Sorry, if my question is dumb, I am just not sure what you are asking for.